# $(-a)^2=a^2$ in commutative ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Maybe this is a silly question, but

> how can I show that $(-a)^2=a^2$ in a commutative ring with $1$ for all $a$ in the ring?

I know that $(-a)^2=(-a)\cdot(-a) =(-1)\cdot(-1)\cdot a^2$. So I have to show that $(-1)^2=1$, in other words, I have to prove that the inverse of $-1$ is $-1$. And is it necessary to have a $1$?  Thanks.

Comment: No, it is not necessary to have a $1$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try squaring both sides of the equation $1 + (-1) = 0,$ or distribute $(1 + (-1))(-1) = 0$.

Comment: thanks for the answer. is it necessary to have a 1 in the ring?

Comment: @Badshah No, nor is commutativity necessary; replace $1$ with $a$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Try expanding $(1 + (-1))^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Neither commutativity nor existence of $1$ is needed.

**Lemma** In a ring $R$ we have $0y=0$ for all $y\in R$.

*Proof.* We have $0y=(0+0)y$, so by the distributive law,
$$
0y=0y+0y.
$$
Adding $-(0y)$ to both sides yields $0=0y$.$\quad\square$

**Theorem** In a ring $R$ the following holds for all $x,y\in R$:
$$
(-x)y=-(xy)
$$

*Proof.* Let's do
$$
xy+(-x)y=(x+(-x))y=0y=0,
$$
by the distributive law and the lemma.$\quad\square$

Similarly, $x(-y)=-(xy)$.

Thus
$$
(-a)^2=(-a)(-a)=-(a(-a))=-(-(aa))=a^2.
$$

Note that we haven't used commutativity nor $1$.